# The value of the sequence generated by the substitution

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, symbolic-dynamics

Given a substitution $1\to 100$, $0\to 01$, then we have $1\to 100\to1000101\to10001010110001100\to\cdots$, we denote this limits (fixed point of this substitution) as $(a_n)$, given  $\beta>1 $. How can we find the value  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{a_n}{\beta^n}$?

Comment: Why do you need to know this? Some context would make it a better question.

Comment: What sort of answer do you expect? Even for the Thue-Morse sequence, for instance, and $\beta=2$, this value is known to be transcendental (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Thue-MorseConstant.html).

Comment: Yes, I realize  that the the value of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n\beta^{-n}$ may not be calculated easily, so I can  estimate this value. I think that  we can find a subshift of finite type, and the problem then can be translated over. I remember the Mauldin-Williams' graph-directed self-similar sets could be one of the choices.

Comment: Subshift of finite type for what?

Comment: The substitution is defined by that rule and the forbidden blocks can appear in the sequence(fixed points of substitution). We can define a SFT, of course, the SFT may be big.